# ADO.NET DataSet. How to display fields from related table and insert records?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, ado.net

I have 2 tables in my SQL Server database: City and Country. Of course City has relation with Country.

Using Visual Studio 2012 I generated DataSet, DataTables, TableAdapters for these tables:
[image]

I want to display tables in DataGridViews and the City DGW should have CountryName column.

So I modified the SelectCommand in City TableAdapter.

```
SELECT City.Id, City.CountryId, City.CityName, Country.CountryName
FROM City 
    INNER JOIN Country ON City.CountryId = Country.Id
```

[image]

```
private void LoadTables()
{
    tableadapterCountry.Fill(dbDataSet.Country);
    tableadapterCity.Fill(dbDataSet.City);
}
```

It works, but I also want to be able to add records to the tables.

For Country table I did it like this:

```
private void AddCountry(string countryName)
{
    dbDataSet.Country.AddCountryRow(countryName);
}
```

And here is how I save to database:

```
private void SaveChanges()
{
    tableadapterCountry.Update(dbDataSet.Country);
    tableadapterCity.Update(dbDataSet.City);
}
```

But in City table I have extra field CountryName. So in dbDataset.City.AddCityRow(...) I need to fill that field. It doesn't feel right, I would like it to happen somehow automatically.

I also tried to manually create DataRow via dbDataset.City.NewRow(), fill it with CityName, CountryId and add using dbDataset.City.Rows.Add(dr):

```
private void AddCity(int countryId, string cityName)
{
    var dr = dbDataSet.City.NewRow();
    dr["CountryId"] = countryId;
    dr["CityName"] = cityName;
    dbDataSet.City.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

But the CountyName field in DGW remains empty even after SaveChanges(), and it fills only when I restart the app/fill tables from adapters again.

**UPD:** [test project + db create sql script (VS 2012, SQL Server Express 2012)](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17976179/__demos/adoCities/adoCities.zip)

Comment: does the countryname show when you call Update() after you executed AddCity()?

Comment: @PrfctByDsgn as I said, no:
"the CountyName field in DGW remains empty even after SaveChanges(), and it fills only when I restart the app/fill tables from adapters again."

Comment: sorry ... missed that ... what exactly did you bind the the DataSource of your DataGridView? dbDataSet.City? I just wrote a simple test program ... there it worked like a charm ... even without calling update ...

Comment: @PrfctByDsgn Yes. Here is my test project https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17976179/__demos/adoCities/adoCities.zip